# getting weighted average then grouping in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have the following dataframe.

```
      weight       x     value
0          5     -8.7        2
1          9     -8.7        3
2         12    -21.4       10
3         32    -21.4       15
```

I need to get weighted average of the value and grouped on x. Result will be:

-8.7: (5/(5+9) * 2) + ((9/14) * 3) = 2.64

-21.4: ((12/44) * 10) + ((32/44) * 15) = 13.63

```
         x     weighted_value
0     -8.7               2.64
1    -21.4              13.63
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Do you have any code that you can post to make it easier for us to help?

Answer (score 1):

`numpy.average` admits a `weights` argument:

```
import io
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

data = io.StringIO('''\
      weight       x     value
0          5     -8.7        2
1          9     -8.7        3
2         12    -21.4       10
3         32    -21.4       15
''')
df = pd.read_csv(data, delim_whitespace=True)

df.groupby('x').apply(lambda g: np.average(g['value'], weights=g['weight']))
```

Output:

```
x
-21.4    13.636364
-8.7      2.642857
dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a vectorized approach using NumPy tools -

```
# Get weighted averages and corresponding unique x's
unq,ids = np.unique(df.x,return_inverse=True)
weight_avg = np.bincount(ids,df.weight*df.value)/np.bincount(ids,df.weight)

# Store into a dataframe
df_out = pd.DataFrame(np.column_stack((unq,weight_avg)),columns=['x','wghts'])
```

Sample run -

```
In [97]: df
Out[97]: 
   weight     x  value
0       5  -8.7      2
1       9  -8.7      3
2      12 -21.4     10
3      32 -21.4     15

In [98]: df_out
Out[98]: 
      x      wghts
0 -21.4  13.636364
1  -8.7   2.642857
```